# Run0time error '438'

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error, vlookup

I have the below line that is receiving a "Object doesn't support the property or method error, but i am not seeing any issues.

```
Dim compliance As Worksheet
Dim report As Worksheet
Dim completeList As Worksheet

Sub getcompliance()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim n As Long
    Dim Source As String
    Set compliance = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Compliance")
    Set report = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Report")
    For i = 3 To report.UsedRange.Rows.Count
      For n = 2 To compliance.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        report(i, 19) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(report("i, 3"), compliance("A1:AC2400"), 29, False)
      Next n
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, of course i realized missing the Cell and Range after i post but the additional information really helped. However it runs now but i am getting an #N/A value when i know the value is there.

Comment: Is there a type issue, e.g. one worksheet contains the value as a number, and the other worksheet contains it as text?

Answer (score 3):

Your line saying

```
report(i, 19) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(report("i, 3"), compliance("A1:AC2400"), 29, False)
```

should probably say

```
report.Cells(i, 19) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(report.Cells(i, 3), compliance.Range("A1:AC2400"), 29, False)
```

but, if so, why are you doing that in a `For n` loop?

Perhaps you mean your code to be:

```
Dim compliance As Worksheet
Dim report As Worksheet
Dim completeList As Worksheet

Sub getcompliance()
    Dim i As Long
    Set compliance = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Compliance")
    Set report = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Report")
    For i = 3 To report.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        report.Cells(i, 19) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(report.Cells(i, 3), compliance.Range("A1:AC" & compliance.UsedRange.Rows.Count), 29, False)
        'Or, simply using the full columns:
        'report.Cells(i, 19) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(report.Cells(i, 3), compliance.Range("A:AC"), 29, False)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I would probably just use `compliance.Range("A:AC")`. There doesn't seem to be a significant detriment to using full column references as the lookup range for vlookup whether on the worksheet or in VBA. I *would* however, use `Application.VLookup` instead of `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup` or use `application.match` to retrieve the row number and then `cells(# from match, 29)`.

Comment: I would normally use "A:AC" myself, but I was trying to work out how to incorporate `n` into the OP's code - so I could only assume that they were thinking they could use it to limit rows in the VLookup.  As for `Application.VLookup` v `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup`, I think I used `Application.VLookup` in a recent answer and one of the other more "senior" (i.e. higher rep) answerers pointed out that it is better to use early-binding rather than late-binding. I can't win!  :D

Comment: I'd have to check specifically about vlookup but you can pass an `application.match` back to a variant and then test the variant with IsError. You cannot do tjhe same with `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match` (so I never use it).

Answer (score 2):

```
'      vvvvv                                          vvvvvvvvvvvvv
report.Cells(i, 19) = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(report.Cells(i, 3), compliance.Range("A1:AC2400"), 29, False)
'                                                                              ^^^^^^
```